# Aptana git integration

Tags: git, aptana3

What is the current state of Aptana git integration:
- is there a good included plugin and how do I access it? 
- it looks like there is a console that I can use for command-line use of git. Is there anything idiosyncratic I need to know about it, or does it work just like it does in bash, zsh, etc?

Comment: It is usable but you may find surprises. It is included AFAIK. There is a console and it sort of works. Generally I keep a separate cmd.exe window open and just use that. Relying on Aptana's terminal led to some failed screen wipes and the inability to use Ctrl+C to leave insert/edit mode in the commit message editor. Using the GUI sometimes led to inaccurate dirty/clean/staged icons. Maybe if I had worked at it more... Right click a file and choose 'Initialize Git repository' to get it going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usable but you may find surprises. It is included AFAIK. There is a console and it sort of works. Generally I keep a separate cmd.exe window open and just use that. Relying on Aptana's terminal led to some failed screen wipes and the inability to use Ctrl+C to leave insert/edit mode in the commit message editor. Using the GUI sometimes led to inaccurate dirty/clean/staged icons. Maybe if I had worked at it more... Right click a file and choose 'Initialize Git repository' to get it going.

Answer (score 0):

Install GitHub for Mac. It will install the required libraries and it's simple. You will be able to perform pull and push operations using the ui. I would suggest using a terminal for other operations rather than aptana CLI.

You can download that app over here: mac.github.com/